# why are there spots of maximal ambient occlusion?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, artifacts, ambient-occlusion

I get strange spots of maximal ambient occlusion.

To reproduce the problem I set up a little example.

What I've done:

- added a Plane
- subdivide it several times
- applied a displacement mod with a cloud texture
- setup ambient occlusion (set pink color to highlight it)
- set auto smooth to as smooth as can be (180°)

as result I got a mesh with strange spots with maximal ambient occlusion. (Pic 1)

When I triangulate the mesh it gets better but there are still a strange spots. (Pic 2)

Rendered with Eevee there seems to be no such behavior. (Pic 3)

I must say that I'm a beginner to blender, maybe I've done something wrong?

I've uploaded the  [.blend File](https://gofile.io/d/o3KEe0) .

( [alternative .blend download](https://ufile.io/q4r20qa6) )

[image: ao test 1]
[image: ao test 2 triangulated]
[image: ao test 3 Eevee]

Comment: Interesting, because changing the world location of the plane varies the effect! AO is achieved by casting rays.. there seems to be some (floating-point?) limit on tolerances, somewhere. casting  from smooth-shade-interpolated normals of a low-poly surface. I wonder if the ray is hitting the face it was cast from?.... 1 level of subdiv. fixes. You wouldn't really expect AO to work that well on low-poly meshes anyway?

Comment: "changing the world location of the plane varies the effect"

Can't confirm this (Cycles). When I grab the mesh and move it the affect stays in place.
Update: But rotation and scaling has. 

My original landscape is huge and I have to heavily reduce geometry.

Comment: I got it to vary in Cycles in the viewport, shading smooth, AO straight to ouptput, object-mode moving up and down along Z. I'd changed clipping distance max to 100, maybe that was it. Anyway, no way should viewing-angle, distance to camera, affect AO, without some error, somewhere...

Comment: So my current (bad) workaround for a large landscape is to increase the geometry in those places in combination with the smoothing in sculpt mode.